# Simple question about equivalence of two forms of PCA as trace maximization over an implicit distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

This may be a soft question of sorts.

One formulation of principal component analysis is trace maximization: $$\arg\max_U \mathbb{E}_x \ [tr(U^Txx^TU)],$$

for $U^TU\le I$ and we assume that there is some underlying distribution.

My question is that I have also seen this written with the quantity inside the trace as $$\arg\max_P \mathbb{E}_x \ [tr(Pxx^T)],$$
where $P$ is an orthogonal projector.

These are the same, right? Any orthogonal projector $P$ is of the form $U^tU$ and the trace is invariant under cyclic permutations, giving the equivalence. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

(*Presumably $P$ and $U$ are also subject to the constraint that $\operatorname{rank}(P)\le k$ and $\operatorname{rank}(U)\le k$* for some $k$.)

Not exactly. Your argument does not justify that
$$
\max_{P^2=P=P^T} \mathbb{E}_x \ [\operatorname{tr}(Pxx^T)]
\ge \max_{U^TU\preceq I} \mathbb{E}_x \ [\operatorname{tr}(U^Txx^TU)],\tag{1}
$$
because the condition that $U^TU\preceq I$ does not imply that $UU^T$ is an orthogonal projector. (It justifies the reversed inequality, though.)

To justify $(1)$, observe that $A=\mathbb{E}_x [xx^T]$ is positive semidefinite. Therefore $A=QDQ^T$ for some real orthogonal matrix $Q$ and diagonal matrix $D$ whose diagonal entries are arranged in descending order. Consequently, under the constraints that $U^TU\preceq I$ and $\operatorname{rank}(U)\le k$, $\mathbb{E}_x \ [\operatorname{tr}(U^Txx^TU)]$ is maximised when $U=UU^T=Q(I_k\oplus0_{(n-k)\times(n-k)})Q^T$. Since $UU^T$ is an orthogonal projector, $(1)$ follows.